# angularjs and requirejs with ui-sortable issue

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui-sortable

i have problem requirejs with ui-sortable .
when  i use ui-sortable without requirejs it is work for me but use requirejs it is not work and not show error for me .
bellow is my code :
page=>config.js

```
shim:{
    'angular': {
        deps: ["jquery","jquery-ui"]
    },
    'app': {
        deps: ['angular','ui-sortable','uploadModule']
    },
    'jquery-ui': {
        deps: ["jquery"]
    },
    'ui-sortable':{
        deps: ['jquery-ui','angular']
    },
    'uploadModule':{
        deps: ['angular','ui-sortable','SplitFilter']
    }

}

require(['app'], function(){
    angular.bootstrap(document , ['app']);
});
```

page=>app.js

```
define(function () {

   angular.module('app' ,  ["coreModule","ui.sortable","uploadModule"]);

});
```

page=>uploadModule.js

```
define(function() {

var UploadMedia = angular.module('uploadModule',['ui.sortable']);
UploadMedia.controller('UploadMedia',function ($scope,$http) {

        $scope.items = ["super", "génial", "trop top", "inouïe"];
});
```

page=>layout

```
 <div class="panel panel-danger text-center mediabox" data-ng-controller="UploadMedia" >
                <div class="panel-heading"> Media </div>
                <div class="panel-body"  >

                    <ul ui-sortable="{axis:'y'}" ng-model="items">
                        <li ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">@{{item}} </li>
                    </ul>


                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please edit the post by including the error.

Comment: no error to show but ui-sortable no effect